# Applications of minty-browder method to systems of partial differential equations

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, parabolic-pde

Can I use the minty-browder method (pseudomonotone operators) to solve the following system of partial differential equations:
$u_{t}^{\gamma}-\text{div}(A(u)\nabla u^{\gamma})=f^{\gamma}(u,\nabla u^{\gamma})$, where $\gamma \in \{1,\ldots,m\}$ and the functions $f^{\gamma}$ are bounded?